# enterprise architech export a Use Case to excel

Tags: excel, vbscript, jscript, enterprise-architect

i have a use case Diagram like this:[Use Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDobe.png)

can i export to a excel the name and descriptions? using a script ?

Comment: Your diagram appears to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. There are two ways. One is a package export. From the browser use `Import/Export / CSV...` for the package which can export the according package with the use case(s). The second is to adapt the csv export script which can be found in Scripting/EAScriptLib (you need to enable the according MDG).

Comment: can u show me a example? how can i do this? im starting with script

Comment: You need to customize that script. Use the JScript-CSV. It has pretty much documentation to help you adapting it the right way.

Comment: Thanks @thomas-kilian

Comment: Can u help me to adapt the CSV export? @Thomas-Kilian

Comment: If you have a concrete question, ask it. Else: this site is not a tutorial point...

Comment: You need to ask a new question. It's common sense here to leave one question as it is and best clarify, but not replace it by another one. Please revert to the previous and post the new one. Thanks!