# Export to Excel from a Diagram Enterprise Architect

Tags: javascript, excel, vbscript, jscript, enterprise-architect

I'm starting to work with Enterprise Architect and I need to make a script to export all use cases and notes, from a diagram to Excel.
However, the provided CSV export only works for packages, not for diagrams like this:

[image]

If I use the option "view as list", the diagram will show all use cases.
I need something like that, but with Notes, and exported to CSV/Excel.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [enterprise architech export a Use Case to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591727/enterprise-architech-export-a-use-case-to-excel)

Comment: If you want this question to distinguish itself from the other one, you will need to show what you have tried and what is not working, a simple "How to do something?" without evidence of you trying is not relevant on this site

Thomas already gave you two paths to help you, we cannot help you further if you do not show your problems

Comment: @Hue Basically you are right. The new question does not really differ much from the previous one which asks for a general export. However, I think that the focus on a diagram makes it worth a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to relate the export script to the diagram in question. The easiest would be to access the diagram with

```
var dia = Repository.GetCurrentDiagram();
```

which returns the object for the currently open diagram.

The next is to scan the diagram objects and finding the use cases:

```
var dObjs = dia.DiagramObjects; // collection of diagram objects
for (var i = 0 ; i < dObjs.Count ; i++) {
  var dObj = dObjs.GetAt(i); // current diagram object
  var obj = Repository.GetElementByID (dObj).ElementID; // related element
  if (obj.Type == "UseCase") { // only interested in UCs
// this is a UC to export; do the magic here
  }
}
```

Please note that the above was just written out of my head and might have syntax errors. But basically that's the way to go.

N.B.: The required csv export is easiest accomplished by using EAScriptLib's JScript-CSV.

Comment: Should mention that the CSV Export can be done using the JScript-CSV Library available in the EAScriptLib Script Group

Comment: Would be worth mentioning for people using this question as a reference, you have all the information you need in one place, I would edit it in, but the queue is full for some reason